# log-transformed density function not plotting correctly

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to log-transform the x axis of a density plot and get unexpected results. The code without the transformation works fine:

```
library(ggplot2)
data = data.frame(x=c(1,2,10,11,1000))

dens = density(data$x)
densy = sapply(data$x, function(x) { dens$y[findInterval(x, dens$x)] })

ggplot(data, aes(x = x)) +
    geom_density() +
    geom_point(y = densy)
```

[image]

If I add `scale_x_log10()`, I get the following result:

[image]

Apart from the y values having been rescaled, something seems to have happened to the x values as well -- the peaks of the density function are not quite where the points are.

Am I using the log transformation incorrectly here?

Comment: That makes sense, but even if I transform the data in the same way before passing it to `density()` the points and curve don't match.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068689/ggplot2-stat-function-misbehaviour-with-log-scales/31069426

Comment: @RHertel Thanks for the pointer, but this gives points for every bin and not for the original data.

Answer (score 2):

The shape of the density curve changes after the transformation because the distribution of the data has changed and the bandwidths are different.  If you set a bandwidth of (`bw=1000`) prior to the transformation and 10 afterward, you will get two normal looking densities (with different y-axis values because the support will be much larger in the first case).  Here is an example showing how varying bandwidths change the shape of the density.

```
data = data.frame(x=c(1,2,10,11,1000), y=0)

## Examine how changing bandwidth changes the shape of the curve
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
greys <- colorRampPalette(c("black", "red"))(10)
plot(density(data$x), main="No Transform")
points(data, pch=19)
plot(density(log10(data$x)), ylim=c(0,2), main="Log-transform w/ varying bw")
points(log10(data$x), data$y, pch=19)
for (i in 1:10)
    points(density(log10(data$x), bw=0.02*i), col=greys[i], type="l")
legend("topright", paste(0.02*1:10), col=greys, lty=2, cex=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this doesn't really answer my question -- why do I get something completely different with the peaks in different positions with `scale_x_log10()`?

Comment: Ok, but why is the highest peak in the second plot is to the left of the two points that clearly cause it?

Comment: So what's the correct way of getting a density plot on a log scale with the actual data points on the curve?